# To get QT Creator C++ to break point on runtime errors?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, runtime-error, breakpoints

How can I get a C++ project in QT Creator to allow me to debug when a run time error occurs as if it put a breakpoint on that line when it encountered the error?

I'm already using 'Debug' instead of 'Release'.

Comment: I think when you install QtCreator there's a prompt that asks you if you want to use it as the default debugger...

Comment: Breakpoints and the such work ordinarily, if I make it the default debugger then It'll allow the functionality I'm after?

Comment: Only one way to find out! ;)

Comment: I didn't really want to reinstall it.

Comment: There is an option to "Debug" on the error QTCreator gives, but it does nothing. I think QT Creator probbably already is debugging or I wouldn't get all the debugging it already does.

Comment: Are you clicking Run (green arrow) or Debug (green arrow with bug)? The latter should bring you to your break point. The former will not.

Comment: Thanks, that may do it, I didn't relise that symbol was a bug :¬P I haven't got a breakpoint at the moment, I need it to make one wherever the code fails. When I can test this next I'll tell you if it worked.